# List of newest questions with wildcard tag is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, wildcards

If you compare the list of questions for the wildcard tag `opengl*`:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl*` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl*))

with the list of questions for the tag `opengl`:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl))

you would expect the wildcard tag to show more questions than the tag without the wildcard. But if you sort by newest questions and take a look at the second page (with 30 per page) you'll notice that the wildcard tag shows older questions there and is missing quite a few questions that are shown in the non-wildcard tag.

The same happens for example for `drupal` and `drupal*`.

This is also not a temporary glitch, this has been broken for at least half a year now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed some time ago (there's also an older bug report somewhere :-). Marking as completed.